# How to disallow implicit any?

Tags: typescript, tslint

I am using TSLint with `"no-any": true, "no-unsafe-any": true`. It disallow:

```
let foo: any;
```

However it still allows:

```
let foo;
```

How to turn on the rule for implicit any?

Comment: Give foo a type.

Comment: `foo` in you second example is not `any` but `undefined`. If you use it it will get another type (ts tests the control flow).

Answer (score 22):

As of now there is no option in tslint to achieve that.
You could use the typescript compiler option `"noImplicitAny": true`, which can be configured using `tsconfig.json`.

Reference : https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/compiler-options.html

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what does TSLint do, that the normal type checker in VS Code doesn't?

Comment: @Kokodoko By using TSLint you can also use the linter outside of your dev environment and integrate the linting rules in your repositories Eg: if your colleagues are not using VSCode or if you want to force linters to run on CI tools like Jenkins etc