# Typescript prevent inferring types except at variable declaration

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

There's a few questions around implicit `any` types in Typescript but none that I've found answer my question.

Say I have this:

```ts
let thing;
thing = 'someValue';
thing = 'someOtherValue';
```

The variable `thing` will now have the type `any`.

[image]

How can I prevent this situation where a variable is declared without a type annotation AND without being immediately assigned a value with a concrete type? I'm using ESLint and found the rule `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment` but that doesn't cover this case.

**PLEASE NOTE** the [suggested duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344033/how-to-disallow-implicit-any) doesn't really answer my question. I already have `strict` enabled in the TS compiler options, which causes `noImplicitAny` to also be enabled, however `noImplicitAny` doesn't do enough for me.

What I want is to not be allowed to create a variable of type `any` except by explicitly annotating the type as `any`. It's very inconvenient that a variable created near the top of a block can have its type inferred many lines further down AND in multiple places, meaning my IDE can't tell me the type until *after* I've used the variable. I would much rather that my types must be declared at the time I create the variable.

**Examples:**

```ts
// Good
let thing: string;
...
thing = 'someValue';

// Good
let thing = 'someValue';

// Good
let thing = SomeFunctionWithAnnotatedReturnType();

// Bad
// This is what I want to prevent
let thing;
...
thing = '123';
...
thing = 123;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to disallow implicit any?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47344033/how-to-disallow-implicit-any)

Comment: @ObsidianAge That answer doesn't seem to be working for me. I already had `strict` enabled so I should have `noImplicitAny` enabled as well, but even with it explicitly enabled, VS Code doesn't complain in the situation above nor does Typescript have anything to say about it.

Comment: @ObsidianAge I see. TS does static flow analysis to determine what the type is _at use time_. That's not really what I want, though. I want to prevent doing `let thing;` without annotating the type. Is there a way to prevent creating a variable of type `any` except if that type is explicitly annotated?

Comment: It's not *really* an `any` type; instead, it is *auto-typed* which evolves based on assignments, as documented [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#improved-any-inference) and mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18679) and [here](//github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12002) and other places.  You can [see the difference](https://tsplay.dev/N7y1GW).  This behavior is not something you can disable, as far as I know.  Does that fully address your question? If so I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I get that it's not _really_ `any`, but that's the only way I could think to describe it. So yes, I want to prevent that behaviour. If I try to declare a variable without a type in C# I get a compiler error. I want C#-like behaviour because I find the Typescript behaviour dangerous. In C# I can have the compiler infer the type by using `var`, but _only_ if the type can be immediately determined. I can't do `var someVar;` in C# because the compiler has nothing from which to infer the type.

Comment: Right, but TS doesn’t work this way.TS is concerned both with type safety and enabling idiomatic JS patterns. In this case, the evolving type of the variable is both type safe (how is it “dangerous?”) and allows people to write JS without type annotations. The links in my previous comment show that this is intended, non-configurable behavior. If I write this up as an answer, would it fully address your question (even though it’s not the answer you were hoping for)?  Or am I misunderstanding your question in some way? Im trying to determine how to proceed, so a or from you would be helpful.

Comment: @jcalz Yeah that technically answers my question. However I don't think "TS doesn't work this way" makes any sense. TS works however we tell it to work. It already prevents you doing stuff you can do in JS by type annotations alone. All TS does is make JS safer and easier to use. Maybe you think a config that breaks standard JS shouldn't be part of TS. In that case it can be a linter rule. It doesn't matter to me _how_ the rule is enforced, only that it is. Since I've been unable to find such a rule, I've [proposed one](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/5526).

Comment: @jcalz As far as being "dangerous", I later realised that the worst that can happen is that the variable ends up with a wider union of types, meaning it won't fit anywhere a narrower union is specified. So yeah, not dangerous, just annoying because my IDE can't tell me the type. _"this is intended, non-configurable behavior"_ ...within TS, sure. But my question encompassed linters as well, which is why I didn't immediately say "yes, your comment would make a good answer". However since I have found no linter rules that match my requirements, I'm happy to accept your comment as an answer.

Comment: Yeah, I don’t have as much expertise with linters as I do with plain TS so if there were such a setting somewhere I’d be less likely to know about it (although the linked GitHub issues just have TS team members say “this is as intended” and not “but you might want such-and-such linter rule”). As for whether it doesn’t make sense that “TS doesn’t work this way” I can only point to the TS design goal documentation that says there is a tradeoff between type safety and productivity and it is not a goal to maximize the former at the expense of the latter. I can add that to my answer if you like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After discussions between many people and much googling, I eventually [proposed a Typescript ESLint rule](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/5526). To my great surprise, what I want is already possible with the following ESLint rule, seen working [here](https://typescript-eslint.io/play/#ts=4.7.4&sourceType=module&showAST=es&code=PQKgUApgzgNglgOwC4AIEHsC0AnaTtwDGSEAJplAJ7ICGAHgFwoDaYKKARBNtuthwBo2KAN7D2HKBBgRifDkw4A1GgRoAjGQBFZMVTSRx0CZgGtEpFAF4UAchlJbAXRQA+FCrWaIOwnuwGfMyIcKg2CACuMDBODBhIABTBpAB0SJQADhAAggjxBkYITgCUguKcALbQUDQA5hAKnAAKvABucKQQKDQo6VndeehIBcYcwgC+YE5gIMBgYMDAKABCNKRgDihQ6FWeAIwA3GDbu6p71nZ7AEwAzLZHJxD7F9c3RwtLAOLo6Oubj54rkwoPhELUHjsnqorhdbACaDAIhB7vNFihvr8NhBUPDsDdYfDEcj3miMX9sVtIZ4ACwXepIADK0lkhmMCWKJK+P3JOKpqgArBdcfiAPx2VoIpEAeQQyJQTFsEqJABUAO7oe5AA&eslintrc=N4KABGBEBOCuA2BTAzpAXGYBfEWg&tsconfig=N4KABGBEDGD2C2AHAlgGwKYCcDyiAuysAdgM6QBcYoEEkJemy0eAcgK6qoDCAFutAGsylBm3QAacDUhFYASSSomyPAEEiATwphR6KQF8Q+oA):

```json
"no-restricted-syntax": [
    "error",
    {
        "selector": "VariableDeclaration[kind = 'let'] > VariableDeclarator[init = null]:not([id.typeAnnotation])",
        "message": "Type must be inferred at variable declaration"
    }
]
```

I didn't know that was possible and it opens up a whole lot more possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

I can’t leave a comment as I don’t have enough reputation, but I find your question doesn’t make a lot of sense. You don’t want to annotate a type or give it a value while at the same time not allowing it to have the type any? What type exactly do you want it to have when giving no indication of a type?

If you want it to be able to have a few specific types later down in your code then you can annotate many types for one variable.

```js
let thing: string | number
```

This way, typescript will allow `thing` to be a string or a number, but nothing else.

Comment: _"You don’t want to annotate a type or give it a value while at the same time not allowing it to have the type any?"_ No, the opposite; I want to be prevented from doing that. If I try to declare a variable without a type in C# I get a compiler error. I basically want C#-like behaviour because I find the Typescript behaviour dangerous. In C# I can have the compiler infer the type by using `var`, but _only_ if the type can be immediately determined. I can't do `var someVar;` because the compiler has nothing from which to infer the type. I want to be forced to assign a value or annotate a type.

Comment: Actually I suppose it's not actually that dangerous, but it's still annoying. The IDE can't tell me what the type is until the point where I use it.